# Define a property type that extends an abstract class in typescript

Tags: typescript

Exemple:

```
export abstract class A {}

export class B extends A {}

export class C { [key: string]:  typeof extends A};
```

typeof extends A does not work obviously, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `export class C { [key: string]:  typeof A };` --- given `extends` does not provide any extra structural typing semantics just `typeof A` would do.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to be a [mcve]. What are the properties of `C` supposed to be? Right now I can't even tell if you want class *instances* or *constructors*, nor what you plan to do with them in either case. And note that [empty classes make poor examples](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) due to TypeScript's structural type system. You should modify `A` and `B` so their instances are distinguishable; otherwise crazy things like `const a: A = "oops"` are [accepted without error](https://tsplay.dev/Nd38vw).